# How to parse HTML from a JSON array

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jHTMLArea editor, and I'm having a problem with populating my textarea controls with html coming from a json array object. All html elements contains both the forward and backward slashes in them, `<tr \/>`. For example, txtOrganization is a textarea control that accepts html, but when I run the code below, the control is blank.

Also below is a sample of the json array being return from the service. If I enter the data manually like so:

```
$("#txtByline").val('<P>Testess<\/P>\r\n<P>&nbsp;<\/P>');
```

everything works.

```
 function LoadForm(PublicationID) {
    /*
        $("#txtByline").val('');*/
        PublicationID = 41;
        var ajaxOpts = {
            type: "post",
            url: "../JSONService.php?Method=GetPublication&PublicationID=" + PublicationID + "",
            data: "",
            success: function (data) {
                var dataObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
                var opt;
                for (var a = 0; a < dataObject.length; a++) {
                    var item = dataObject[a];
                    $("#txtTitle").val(item.Title);
                    $("#txtSubTitle").val(item.SubTitle);
                    $("#selType").val(item.Type);
                    $("#txtDate").val(item.DateTime);
                    $("#txtContactName").val(item.ContactName);
                    $("#txtContactPhone").val(item.ContactPhone);
                    $("#txtContactEmail").val(item.ContactEmail);
                    $("#txtOrganizationTitle").val(item.OrganizationHTML);
                    $("#txtByline").val(item.Byline);
                    $("#txtBody").val(item.Body);
                    $("#txtClosingBody").val(item.BodyClosing);
                    $("#txtQuote").val(item.Quote);
                    $("#txtDescription").val(item.Description);
                    $("#txtFootnote").val(item.FootNote);
                }
            }
        }



 ([{"Type":"About","Year":"2010","DateTime":"08\/07\/2010","ContactName":"test","ContactPhone":"test","ContactEmail":"test","OrganizationHTML":"<P><A href=\"http:\/\/www.iup.edu\">Orrick<\/A><\/P>","Title":"test","SubTitle":"test","Byline":"<P>Testess<\/P>\r\n<P>&nbsp;<\/P>","Body":"<H1>sdfsdfsdfsdfsd<\/H1>\r\n<H1>dfgdfgdfgdf<\/H1>\r\n<H1>dfgdfgdfdfgdf<\/H1>","BodyClosing":"<UL>\r\n<LI>fghgfhgf<\/LI><\/UL>","Quote":"<P align=center>dfgdfgdfgdf<\/P>","Description":"test","FootNote":"test","IsActive":null,"RegionID":"0","PageID":"0","ID":"41","FileID":null,"FileText":null,"FileUrl":null,"ImageID":null,"ImageCaption":null,"ImagePath":null,"KeyWordID":null,"KeyWords":null,"LinkID":null,"LinkUrl":null,"LinkText":null}])
```

http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/

Comment: is there a reason youre not using the JSON data type on your request?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem: you're overriding the values of the `#txt` elements on every loop so that they end up having the values of the last iteration. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell jHtmlArea to update itself after you set the value of the underlying textarea:

```
$("#txtOrganizationTitle").val(item.OrganizationHTML).htmlarea('updateHtmlArea');
```

In response to your comment:

jHtmlArea doesn't have great documentation (unless you're using [intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) in Visual Studio along with [jHtmlArea's vsdoc file](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63489#690094).) but it's [code](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63489#690095) is not too hard to read through. It follows the same pattern that most jQuery plugins do, so I was able to find out what methods they make available, [updateHtmlArea](http://gist.github.com/514390#LID358) being one of them.

Comment: You're welcome Brandon. I've edited my answer with a response to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function LoadForm(PublicationID) {
        PublicationID = 41;
        var ajaxOpts = {
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "../JSONService.php?Method=GetPublication&PublicationID=" + PublicationID + "",
            data: "",
            success: function (dataObject) {
                var opt;
                jQuery.each(dataObject, function(i,item){
                    $("#txtTitle").val(item.Title);
                    $("#txtSubTitle").val(item.SubTitle);
                    $("#selType").val(item.Type);
                    $("#txtDate").val(item.DateTime);
                    $("#txtContactName").val(item.ContactName);
                    $("#txtContactPhone").val(item.ContactPhone);
                    $("#txtContactEmail").val(item.ContactEmail);
                    $("#txtOrganizationTitle").val(item.OrganizationHTML);
                    $("#txtByline").val(item.Byline);
                    $("#txtBody").val(item.Body);
                    $("#txtClosingBody").val(item.BodyClosing);
                    $("#txtQuote").val(item.Quote);
                    $("#txtDescription").val(item.Description);
                    $("#txtFootnote").val(item.FootNote);
                });
            }
        };

}
```